# React doesn't wait data for fetched [edited]

Tags: reactjs

I gave conditions to `if` in `useEffect()` to wait data for fetched..
`invoice && invoice['data']` like this. 
My expectation was `setMoney()` would work. but It just passes this function. 
`invoice` is fetched data from store.

This is view compoenet.

```js
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import './invoice.scss';
import InvoiceFilter from './invoice_filter';
import InvoiceTable from './invoice_table';
import {invoiceContext} from '@/context/invoice_dataStore';

function Invoice(props) {
  const {invoice, getInvoiceInitialData} = useContext(invoiceContext);
  const [receivable, setReceivable] = useState(0);
  const [pending, setPending] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (invoice && invoice['data']) {
      setMoney();
    }
  }, []);

  function setMoney() {
    if (invoice && invoice['data']) {
      const infoSt = invoice['data'].map((info) => info);
      infoSt.forEach((info) => {
        switch (info.status) {
          case 100: //receivable
            setReceivable((prev) => prev + info.amount);
            break;
          case 200: // Pending
            setPending((prev) => prev + info.amount);
            break;
          default:
            throw new Error('unknown command');
        }
      });
    }
  }


  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="invoice">
          <strong>${receivable}</strong>
          <strong>$ {pending}</strong>
       </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Invoice;
```

- Edited
  before using `useEffect()`, I approached this using only `if`.
  and I don't still get why this didn't work.!

```js
if(invoice && invoice['data']){
    setMoney();
  }
```

because this worked.

```js
let showTable;
if(invoice && invoice['data']){
    showTable = invoice['data'].map((info) => 
      <div>{info.title}</div>)
    }
  }


return (
    <>
     {showTable}
    </>
)
```

Comment: There's no way for us to see how you're sending the request. Please consider adding more details

Comment: I added more details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` with empty dependency array is only called after the initial component mount. It's highly possible that the `invoice` data in your context wasn't populated at the time of the `useEffect` execution.

To fix this, you have to pass `invoice` as a dependency to the `useEffect` hook so that your function can execute when its value changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (invoice && invoice['data']) {
      setMoney();
    }
  }, [invoice]);
```